# Cannot upload videos received through WhatsApp to OneDrive

Tags: whatsapp, onedrive, uploading

I have a Nokia Lumia 630 phone and I usually upload videos and photos received through WhatsApp and Viber to OneDrive. Suddenly the phone has stopped doing that, and when I check the box to save to OneDrive I get a quick message saying "couldn't upload file".

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you get such issue by uploading your files through your Onedrive app ??

Answer (score 1):

On your phone,
Settings>Backup>Photos+Videos
There you will get options for uploading videos to your OneDrive,make sure you have "not" selected "Don't Upload".